# Bézout's identity, finding integers x and y such that ax+by = gcd(a,b)

Tags: c, number-theory

The gcd function in the following code is given in the book Programming Challenges by Steven Skiena as a way of finding integers x and y such that ax+by = gcd(a,b). For example, given that a = 34398 and b = 2132 (whose gcd = 26), the algorithm the code below is meant to execute should return 34398 × 15 + 2132 × −242 = 26. The algorithm to find x and y is based on the base case y = 1 and x = 0 since a * 1+0*0 = gcd(a,0) and according to Euclid's algorithm gcd(34398, 2132) reduces to gcd(gcd(34398, 2132),0) or gcd(26,0). Euclid's algorithm can be applied backwards to find that 34398 × 15 + 2132 × −242 = 26.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() { 
    gcd(34398, 2132, 0, 1);

    /* Find the gcd(p,q) and x,y such that p*x + q*y = gcd(p,q) */
    long gcd(long p, long q, long *x, long *y)
    {
        long x1,y1; /* previous coefficients */
        long g; /* value of gcd(p, q) */

        if (q > p) return(gcd(q, p, y, x));

        if (q == 0) {
            *x = 1;
            *y = 0;
            return(p);
        }

        g = gcd(q, p % q, &x1, &y1);
        *x = y1;
        *y = (x1 - floor(p / q) * y1);
        return(g);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How do you test this code? The required input seems to be the p, q, and the base case x and y values but when I run the program below using the line of code gcd(34398, 2132, 0, 1); there is a runtime error message that states 'conflicting types for gcd'.

Comment: `gcd(34398, 2132, 0, 1);` does not contain two `long*` while your `gcd` function expects `x` and `y` to be `long*`. Increase the warning level of your compiler.

Comment: The code in your question is not valid at all btw. You have put the definition of the `gcd` function inside the `main` function.

Comment: @TedLyngmo — for worse or worse, GCC allows nested functions by default, though the C standard does not.  And that accounts for the 'conflicting types' error message, which (despite the comment in the question) is a compile-time error, not a run-time error.  The presumed type for `gcd` based on the call returns `int` (no assumptions about the types of the arguments); the type defined by the nested definition makes the return type `long`, hence the error.

Comment: You test this like any other code: write tests that pass in pre-determined inputs and compare against known outputs. The code generally has to be designed to allow that, which in C usually means no nested functions. It sounds like you need a C tutorial before you think about testing stuff.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "_GCC allows nested functions_" - Yes, I've seen it before sometime. Horrible. Best just call it invalid (according to the C standard). :)  "_hence the error_" - Ah, that explains it. I just [fixed the code](https://godbolt.org/z/vdzTKKxG7) and assumed OP made an error when copying/pasting/typing in the question. Wasn't sure what to answer when no updates to the question came.

Comment: Compile with `-Wall -Werror -pedantic` and save yourself a lot of hassle.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Re “Best just call it invalid (according to the C standard)”: It is not. The C standard is intended to be extended. It is an open language that people are invited to add things to. The C standard deliberately includes text that says programs using extensions are conforming programs (in the absence of something else that would disqualify them).

Comment: @EricPostpischil I need to work on how I formulate these things :-) Perhaps "_ISO C forbids nested functions_"  (like gcc says it) would be a better wording?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: GCC’s phrasing is wrong; ISO C allows nested functions. “Nested functions are not strictly conforming” is correct. Or “Nested functions not allowed in pedantic mode” or “Nested functions not allowed in strictly conforming programs” or “Nested functions are an extension [not allowed in pedantic mode]”, et cetera.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Is there anything that ISO C does not allow in a conforming program? Can this comment be a conforming C program if I quickly cobble up a clang plugin that recognises it, issues a diagnostic, and accepts it as a program that does nothing? If not, why not?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: If a program has a `#error` directive that is not skipped by conditional inclusion, it cannot be accepted by a conforming C implementation (C 2018 4 4). Other than that, you could probably technically get away with accepting almost anything. But of course the intent is not to get too wacky; the intent is for somebody who has learned standard C to be able to port programs to all sorts of implementations and to use their extensions without too much trouble. And nested functions fit within that intent.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Nearly every error (not `#error`) a programmer can make is some other programmer's legitimate and valuable extension. Instead of conforming programs (too broad a category), it makes sense to talk about programs that require or do not require a diagnostic. The phrase "ISO C does not allow X" can be only interpreted in this sense: "ISO C does not allow X *to be silently accepted by a conforming implementation*" I think we should not be required to repeat this ending every single time.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: Re “Nearly every error (not #error) a programmer can make is some other programmer's legitimate and valuable extension”: No. Array overruns are not normal extensions, nor are using memory after freeing it, using one pointer instead of the intended one, etc. Re “The phrase "ISO C does not allow X" can be only interpreted in this sense”: Unfortunately, that attitude has produced, in Stack Overflow at least, an absurd purported belief that anything other than strictly conforming C is not only illegal but bad. People ought to be aware extensions are legitimate…

Comment: … By “purported belief,” I allude to the fact that a number of people rail against going outside the bounds of strictly conforming C, particularly executing anything that is “undefined behavior,” but likely do it all the time themselves. Whenever one calls an operating system library (to draw in a GUI interface, to perform network communications, etc.) or calls to a library written in a language other than C, they enter the dreaded realm of undefined behavior. The nominal statements made do not represent their actual beliefs as manifested by common programming practice. That should be fixed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "Array overruns are not normal extensions". IME this is perhaps *the* most used extension in the field. People traverse 2D arrays as if they were 1D left all the time, which is of course UB. May we have an official list of extensions considered normal? "Unfortunately, that attitude has produced" I find this attitude healthy, and what it produces quite desirable. No extension should be allowed unless there is a specific need to use one, the programmers understand what they are doing, and document their choice. Otherwise it is as good as illegal.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: “I find this attitude healthy, and what it produces quite desirable. No extension should be allowed unless there is a specific need to use one, the programmers understand what they are doing, and document their choice.”: That is not what the attitude produces. Remember, we are not discussing the attitude that you can use extensions if you document that; we are discussing the attitude that anything that is not strictly conforming C is disallowed. That attitude produces students who are misinformed and people who practice things different from what they preach.

Comment: Yes, anything that is not strictly conforming C is disallowed unless you demonstrate a **need**. This is not up to discussion, them's the rules, like them or leave.

Comment: Wow, I did learn a lot from this! First lesson "Do stick your nose out, you'll get great responses".
Next lesson: I do not know s*hit about C. I need Merlin. - Eric and "the number that can't be ..."  thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration `long gcd(long p, long q, long *x, long *y)` says the last two parameters of `gcd` are pointers. So you must pass it pointers to existing `long`; you cannot pass it values such as `0` and `1`.

To do that, define two `long` objects in `main`, possibly also called `x` and `y`, such as `long x = 0, y = 1;`. Then pass pointers to those objects to `gcd`, as with `gcd(34398, 2132, &x, &y);`.

Further, you must put the declaration of `gcd` before any use of it.

Defining `gcd` inside `main` is an extension to the C standard. That extension is useful in situations where the nested function needs certain context from its containing function. There is no need for that here, so the function should be defined in the ordinary way. Move the entire definition of `gcd` from inside `main` to before `main`.

There is no reason to use `floor` in `floor(p / q)`, because `p` and `q` have integer type and integer division will be performed. There will be no fraction part for `floor` to remove. It can actually make the result wrong if the `double` type has less precision than the `long` type. So just use `p/q`.

There is also no reason to use recursion in this code. It is wasteful and not pedagogical in this situation. (Referring to [the book *Programming Challenges*](http://acm.cs.buap.mx/downloads/Programming_Challenges.pdf), the author says “Euclid’s algorithm  is recursive…” However, I have a 2003 English translation of Euclid’s *Elements*, circa 300 BCE. Looking at Euclid’s GCD algorithm in Book VII, Propositions 1 and 2, I would say it is iterative, not recursive. In its cumbersome way, as seen through modern eyes, it describes doing things repeatedly, not reapplying the whole algorithm *de novo*.)

Comment: Personally I have found that proving the correctness of the *extended* euclidean algorithm is much simpler for the recursive version.